# Qmake on Windows

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++, qmake

I have a project written in Qt that I have no problems compiling and running on Linux. The command line is:

```
qmake ../trunk/GSDTesting.pro
```

The process on Linux was really simple: install a few dependencies using `apt` and you are off.

My task is to recompile the same program on Windows using Visual Studio C++ compiler, but the problem is I don't know how to start. There is no such thing as `qmake` for Windows.

Can someone give me a few hints where to start. Please note that I don't know QT almost at all, my task is just to debug some issue unrelated to QT.

Comment: ***There is no such thing as qmake for Windows.*** It's included with the Qt framework. One of the first steps in building Qt from source is to compile qmake on windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using terminal exclusively on Windows? If so, maybe this image of example build steps straight from Qt Creater 4.14.2 may help you:

[image: Sample build steps, local build of Qt]

As you can see the image of the default Qt creator build steps list the file path where 'qmake.exe' can be located on a local installation of the toolchain.

If you can use a machine with a display I find using the Qt creator GUI is not all that bad.

Here is a link to the base get started page:
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/gettingstarted.html

Here is a link to the installer download page:
https://www.qt.io/download

**IMPORTANT:**

You will need to make a Qt account, login to your account, and then download the open-source version of the API. The commercial version of the same source is acquired differently/seperately.

Otherwise, if you cannot use the GUI, can I request some clarification on why you cannot use Qt creator on your Windows installation?

Comment: Yes, you are right, there is qmake.exe for Windows, it just wasn't in my installation.